# print 2 functions output in a single line - powershell

Tags: powershell

Can we print two function output in the same line?

```
function dateHost {
    $date = get-date
    $host = "$env:compname"
    write-host"date=$date;hostname=$host;"
}

function service {
    if ($Service.Status -eq "running"){ 
        Write-Host "message=$ServiceName service is already started"
    }
}
```

I want to print the output of these 2 function in one line.

```
date=26 sept 2016;host=localhost;message=servicename already started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this by avoiding `Write-Host` within the functions and instead just return the strings as their output. Also note that you can't assign to the var `$host` as this refers to the predefined PowerShell host so I changed that name to `$hostname`

```
function dateHost {
    $date = get-date
    $hostname = "$env:compname"
    "date=$date;hostname=$hostname;"
}

function service{
    if ($Service.Status -eq "running"){ 
        "message=$ServiceName service is already started"
    } 
}

"$(dateHost)$(service)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! this solution would only prints the output of datehost. If i do Write-Host (dateHost+$(service)), will get the output in 2 different lines.

Comment: I think you have still some `Write-Host` calls in your functions - remove them all and try again (maybe even in a clean new session)